# MySQL: Add stoplist

Tags: mysql

How could I add a own stoplist to MySQL 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you're asking about how to set the stopwords list for MySQL `FULLTEXT` search, this portion of the manual page **[11.8.6. Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)** could interest you *(quoting)* :

> To override the default stopword list,
>   **set the `ft_stopword_file` system
>   variable**. *(See [Section 5.1.3, “Server
>   System Variables”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html))* The variable value
>   should be the path name of the file
>   containing the stopword list, or the
>   empty string to disable stopword
>   filtering. 
> The server looks for the
>   file in the data directory unless an
>   absolute path name is given to specify
>   a different directory. 
> After changing
>   the value of this variable or the
>   contents of the stopword file, **restart
>   the server and rebuild your `FULLTEXT` 
>   indexes**.
>
> The stopword list is free-form. That
>   is, you may use any nonalphanumeric
>   character such as newline, space, or
>   comma to separate stopwords.
>   
> Exceptions are the underscore
>   character (“`_`”) and a single
>   apostrophe (“`'`”) which are treated as
>   part of a word. The character set of
>   the stopword list is the server's
>   default character set; see [Section
>   9.1.3.1, “Server Character Set and Collation”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

You have to set the [`ft_stopword_file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) system variable.